# firebase storage flutter post picture is uploaded, but not the profile picture

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

The following code uploads the post picture, but not the profile picture, and I can't seem to find the cause of it.

```
Future<String> uploadImage(
  String childName, Uint8List file, bool isPost) async {
Reference ref =
storage.ref().child(childName).child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid);

if(isPost) {
  String id = const Uuid().v1();
  ref = ref.child(id);
}

UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(file);

TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
return downloadUrl;
}
```

uploading post method:

```
Future<String> uploadPost(String notes, Uint8List file,
  String username, Timestamp datePublished) async {

String res = "Some error occurred";

DocumentSnapshot doc =
await usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).get();
UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);

try {
  String photoUrl = await uploadImage('posts', file, true);

  String postId = const Uuid().v1(); // creates unique id based on time
  Post post = Post(
      note: notes,
      uid: firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid,
      username: user.username!,
      postId: postId,
      datePublished: Timestamp.now(),
      profImage: photoUrl,
      ); 
  usersRef.doc(currentUserId()).collection('posts')
 .doc(postId).set(post.toJson());
  res = "success";
  viewModel.resetData();
} catch (err) {
  res = err.toString();
 }
return res;
}
```

updating profile method:

```
updateProfile(
  { Uint8List? file,
   String? username, email}) async {
DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(currentUserId()).get();
var users = UserModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
users.username = username;
users.email = email;

if (file != null){
  users.photoUrl = await uploadImage('profilePic', file, false);
}
  await usersRef.doc(currentUserId()).set({
    'username': username,
    'photoUrl': users.photoUrl,
    'email': email
  });
  return true;
}
```

update profile is called:

```
editProfile(BuildContext context) async {
FormState? form = formsKey.currentState;
form!.save();
if (!form.validate()) {
  validate = true;
  notifyListeners();
  showInSnackBar(context, Languages.of(context)!.errorEditPro);
} else {
  try {
    loading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    bool success = await userService.updateProfile(
        file: image!,
        username: username,
        email: email);
    if (success) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const 
InputUserData()));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
  loading = false;
  notifyListeners();
}
}
```

Firebase storage creates the posts/ folder where the picture is present. However, it does not create the profilePic/ folder and, thus no picture on the avatar.

This is probably very stupid little thing, but is giving me a lot of headache. Help appreciated, thanks!

the error log:

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///photoUrl

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2666:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2574:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync 
(package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load 
(package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:505:13)
#5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:380:22)
#6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:503:83)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
```

Comment: Do you get any error when trying to change the profilePic? And can you show the code where updateProfile is called?

Comment: hi! i added the code where the updateProfile is called. The error is the one with the URI. no else.

Comment: Try to figure out what is happening in the `uploadImage` method when you are expecting a profilePic is being uploaded, but it is actually not happening. Maybe the `file` is `null`. Just add a bunch of print statements.

Comment: thanks. will do! stuck with other thing currently.